# Creating static library in a makefile, using linux g++ compiler

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, static-libraries

I have simple files: 
hello.h , hello.cpp

I have created a makefile in order to generate a static library (libhello.a)
but I'm getting error message , what am I doing wrong?

My code is:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
utilObjs = hello.o

libhello.a: $(utilObjs)
    ar rc $@ $(utilObjs)
    ranlib $@

hello: hello.o libhello.a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.o -L ./ -lutil -o $@

hello.o: hello.cpp hello.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $>

clean:
    rm -rf *.o libhello.a hello

all: hello 
.PHONY: all clean
```

The error message :
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated

Comment: The default GNU *make*  rules (you can get them with `make -p`) already have rules to compile C++, using `CXX` not `CC`  etc. And you should use `remake`  to help debugging your `Makefile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `$>` means anything special, change it to `$<`  , which expands to the first prerequisite of the rule. (hello.cpp in this case)